# Applying the Banach's Contraction Principle

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I have a problem:

> For a system of linear equations:
>   $$x_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j+b_i,\ \ i=1,2, \ldots , n \tag 1$$
>   Prove that, if
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}^2 \le q<1$$
>   then $(1)$ has a unique solution.

==================================

My teacher said that We need to use the [Banach's Contraction Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_contraction_principle), but I have trouble when I do it...

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $\pmb{A}$ to be the matrix with entries $a_{i,j}$ for $i,j = 1, \ldots, n$, $\pmb{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $\pmb{b} = (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$. Then your system is equivalent to
$$\pmb{x} = \pmb{A}\pmb{x} + \pmb{b}$$
Define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $f(\pmb{x}) = \pmb{A}\pmb{x} + \pmb{b}$. Equip $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric.

What does it mean for $f$ to be a contraction in this metric space, and what does Banach's theorem say in that case?

Comment: Thanks **Svinepels**. Since your hints, I write: $$d(f(x),f(y))=\left \| Ax-Ay \right \|\le \left \| A \right \|\cdot \left \| x-y \right \|\le q\left \| x-y \right \|,\  q \in (0,1)$$ Is it correct?

Comment: If $||A||$ denotes the matrix norm induced by the Euclidean norm and you have somehow showed that $||A|| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2$ then yes.

Comment: Yes, I have trouble, if we use the Hilbert–Schmidt norm: $$\left \| A \right \|_F=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}^2}$$ then we have: $$d(f(x),f(y))=\left \| Ax-Ay \right \|\le \left \| A \right \|\cdot \left \| x-y \right \|\le \sqrt{q}\left \| x-y \right \|=\sqrt{q}d(x,y),\  q \in (0,1)$$? Do you think so? But If I use the matrix norm: $$\left \| A \right \|_1=\max_{1\le j\le n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$$ which is the maximum absolute column sum of the matrix then can you finish it?. Or can you give me your solution (with the Euclidean norm), and plz, say to me if I have a mistake :) , thanks!

Comment: @ **Svinepels**: :(

Comment: Sorry. The Hilbert-Schmidt norm is *subordinate* to the Euclidean norm on vectors: That is, $||\pmb{A}\pmb{x}||_2 \leq ||\pmb{A}||_F ||\pmb{x}||_2$ for all matrices $\pmb{A}$ and vectors $\pmb{x}$. This should give the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you have derived holds in a given norm.
Now you do not have to show explicitly, that $|| A|| \leq \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2$ holds.  The double sum which you are given is a specific norm(Hilbert-Schmid or Frobenius) and what you essentially have yet to show to be done with the task is that it is consistent with the euclidean norm for vectors.

Comment: Consistency of the Frobenius norm with the euclidean norm  $||Ax||_2^2 = x^t A^t Ax=\sum_i|\sum_j a_{ij} x_j|^2\leq \sum_i (\sum_j |a_{ij}|^2 \sum_j |x_j|^2)= ||A||_F^2 ||x||_2^2 $ (note: the norm is consistent with the euclidean norm but __not__ induced by it). The way I see it you're done. If you want the proof for a different norm you have to use (and probably show) the equivalence of norms on a finite space( 1,2, inf norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: Thank you very much! **Nox**